# Clipping TIFF raster image using bounding box with GDAL in Java

Tags: raster, gdal, java

I would like to know how can I clip a raster image using a bounding box with GDAL in Java.

I can do it with the binary file gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -projwin -75.3 5.5 -73.5 3.7 -of GTiff original.tif new.tif
```

Comment: use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)?